# Website refreshing every min

Tags: python, flask

I am currently building a website that pulls data from a database (it is updated with new information every min). On the front end, it is just html/css/bootstrap. On the back end, I am using flask to connect to my database, where it also pushes the data onto the website.

My question is: Is there a way to retrieve new information from the database every min (in flask) and updates it directly onto the webpage (without having the need to refresh my webpage every min)?

Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand what you mean, could you explain yourself better?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You need AJAX...

Comment: 2 things need to happen every min. 1:running the flask app.py every min so it grabs new data from the database.2: having the html refresh every min

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) in your JavaScript to call a JavaScript function that pings your API backend every minute:

```
const getData = fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => console.log(response.json()))

setInterval(getData, 60000)
```